# How to remove text from XmlNode?

Tags: c#, xml

Let's say, I've got a XmlNode:

```
<A>1</A>
```

How to remove a text from it, so I get:

```
<A />
```

instead of:

```
<A></A>
```

Below is a unit test which shows what I tried so far.

```
  [Test]
  public void RemoveXmlTextTest()
  {
     string xmlString = @"<B><A>1</A></B>";         
     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
     doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
     XmlNode testNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//A");

     //1. Set innerText to string.Empty - not working
     //testNode.InnerText = String.Empty;

     //2. Call removeAll - not working         
     //testNode.RemoveAll();

     //3. testNode has one child with name '#text' - remove it - not working
     //testNode.RemoveChild(testNode.FirstChild);

     //4. Replace node with a new empty one - working but extremally ugly :(
     //All references to testNode still points to the old one !!!!
     testNode.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(doc.CreateElement(testNode.Name), testNode);

     //Is there some better way to do it?

     testNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//A");
     Assert.AreEqual("<A />", testNode.OuterXml);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting [`XmlElement.IsEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.isempty.aspx) to true?

(Obviously this means casting to `XmlElement`, but that's the only situation in which the question makes sense.)